# cassandra Failed to classify files in /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33

Tags: cassandra

cassandra 3.6

openjdk version "1.8.0_91"

when I start cassandra service will throw this error.

```
INFO  05:57:10 Initializing system_schema.keyspaces
INFO  05:57:10 Initializing system_schema.tables
ERROR 05:57:10 Failed to classify files in /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f
Some old files are missing but the txn log is still there and not completed
Files in folder:
        /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f/ma-404-big-CompressionInfo.db
        /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f/ma-404-big-Data.db
        /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f/ma-404-big-Digest.crc32
        /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f/ma-404-big-Filter.db
        /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f/ma-404-big-Index.db
        /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f/ma-404-big-Statistics.db
        /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f/ma-404-big-Summary.db
        /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f/ma-404-big-TOC.txt
Txn: [ma_txn_compaction_4c1ecb40-0ff9-11e8-a162-c50ddd47b4bb.log in /var/lib/cassandra/data/system_schema/columns-24101c25a2ae3af787c1b40ee1aca33f]
```

what does it means and what should I have to do to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer.

system files are corrupted and getting issues.

so you need to delete all direcory inside "/var/lib/cassandra/data/" except your keyspace.

*Note: Don't remove your keyspace data.

Comment: is this operation affect keyspace data ?